# ReactJS + Netlify Hosting ... stellar.toml downloading when navigating to /.well-known/stellar.toml

Tags: stellar.toml

Stemming off of this converstaion

https://galactictalk.org/d/2199-how-to-set-up-a-stellar-toml-file-with-reactjs-nodejs-stack/14

I have been able to identify that when using netlify to build a react app, that a .htaccess file is not used by netlify. Instead, the netlify.toml file is used to configure any custom headers. I have the following inside of the netlify.toml file

```
[build]
base = "crypto-movez/"
publish = "crypto-movez/build/"
command = "npm run-script build"


[[headers]]
    for = "/.well-known/stellar.toml"
    [headers.values]
        Content-Type = "text/plain"
        Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "*"
```

after conversating with some devs on the KeyBase app, it was suggested that I bring the question here to be able to receive additional support.

[image]

above is a picture of the file structure. When navigating to the website domain and going to the '/.well-known/stellar.toml', the file is then downloaded.

[image]

above is a picture of the curl response I am getting. I know that the content-type needs be returning as text/plain, and even though i am setting the headers in the netlify.toml file to allow for that type of content, this is what is coming back.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have looked through as many other explanations possible so if you could please answer specifically that would be AWESOME

Comment: interesting updated.... 
when running a curl directly to the domain (without use of https://) i am now getting the following response

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Thu, 21 Nov 2019 21:53:55 GMT
Location: https://cryptomovez.com/.well-known/stellar.toml
Age: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Server: Netlify
X-NF-Request-ID: 8e94d9e6-72ce-474c-bab6-2716ea9ac07f-159018201
```

if i try to visit the webpage though in browser it still is attempting to download the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the netlify.toml directly, try creating an `_headers` file in the root directory. Then add:

```
# the stellar.toml file route
 /.well-known/stellar.toml  
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Content-Type: text/plain
```

Comment: Can confirm this is how apps hosted on CF Pages does it https://developers.cloudflare.com/pages/platform/headers/